# Characterizing Convergence of a Series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $a_n$ be a convergent series of positive terms. What can be said about the convergence of the following series:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n}{n}$

The series above diverges. We know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n}{n}$ > $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{a_1}{n}$. But we also know, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{a_n}{n}$ diverges. Therefore, even if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $a_n$ converges, we know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n}{n}$ must diverge.

Comment: Sorry, just resolved this.

Comment: Part of this site is that other users can browse questions that have already been answered. If you solved it, it'd probably be helpful to later users for you to post what you found as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What's the sum of the coefficients of $a_1$ in the second sum?

Comment: The co-efficients are $a_1$(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n). Thanks appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

No, your proof has problems: $\sum a_n/n$ need not diverge, and $a_n(1+1/2 +\cdots +1/n)$ need not diverge. Your first assertion

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_1}{n}$$

gives you all you need, because the series on the right diverges.